# Extract continuous measurements from data frame

Tags: r, subset

I would like to subset a data frame that consists of measured time series with corresponding POSIXct timestamps. Here is an example data frame:

```
ExampleData<-data.frame(as.POSIXct(c(1:500, 4845:4860, 61000:62000,
155470 )+1456858328, origin="1970-01-01" ), runif(1518))
```

There are four continuous measurements in it:

```
From 2016-03-01 19:52:09 to 2016-03-01 20:00:28  (500 seconds)
From 2016-03-01 21:12:53 to 2016-03-01 21:13:08  (15 seconds)
From 2016-03-02 12:48:48 to 2016-03-02 13:05:28  (1000 seconds)
From 2016-03-03 15:03:18 to 2016-03-03 15:03:18  (1 seconds)
```

What I want to to is extracting all continuous measurements that are longer than 60 seconds. Coming from Matlab I would write a for loop and count it. I was wondering if there is an "R"-way to do it more elegant?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rle` to find runs of consecutive differences

```
r <- rle(diff(as.numeric(ExampleData[,1])))
cbind(cumsum(r$lengths)-r$lengths+1,cumsum(r$lengths)+1)[r$values==1,]
```

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1  500
[2,]  501  516
[3,]  517 1517
```

This output says there is a run from index 1 to 500, another from index 501 to 516, and another from index 517 to 1517.